# How to trigger CMake to build project before running the debugger in Visual Studio Code

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-code

How can I run CMake (F7) everytime I run the debugger (F5) automatically?

I know that we can configure launch.json to trigger a pre-launch task. So a potential solution would be to invoke the CMake job from there, but I am not sure how.

Note: I am using the CMake extension to configure the build.

Comment: Did you generate the solution file from the cmake project? For cmake always gets invoked by the build process of Visual Studio once the CMakeLists.txt changes.

Comment: CMake does not build the project. CMake only generates the build script (e.g. VS solution/project file, Makefile etc.). CMake only regenerates the project files when it detects changes to the CMakeLists files.

Comment: Sorry guys I should have mentioned that this is on Visual Code, not Visual Studio. I have updated the question.

Comment: Actually... I just checked the edit history of the post, and someone else removed "Visual Code" part of my question... (I though I was getting crazy, but I am not... :)

Comment: @gmagno Edited again. Actually there *is* a tag for that, so I used it instead of `visual-studio`. Also edited the title. At least it doesn't feel like a "tagged title" now.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi +1 for you. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is old but did you figure out how to do it?